# using a simple editor pattern in knockout with nested objects

Tags: knockout.js

I've been following the simple editor pattern on [knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html) and everything worked as expected until I started using nested objects.

Basically when I select an item I'm setting 2 properties on my viewmodel. A `selectedItem` property and an `editable` property. It's the editable property that I then make changes to. If the user accepts the changes then the selected item is updated.

This works fine in my code if I have a flat object. However when I have nested objects the child objects data is not correct when assigned to the editable property.

I should see:

```
"Selected": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "user 1",
    "Role": {
      "Id": 2,
      "RoleName": "IT Support"
    }
  },
  "Editable": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "user 1",
    "Role": {
      "Id": 2,
      "RoleName": "IT Support"
    }
```

However I get:

```
"Selected": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "user 1",
    "Role": {
      "Id": 3,
      "RoleName": "IT Procurement"
    }
  },
  "Editable": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "user 1",
    "Role": {
      "Id": 2,
      "RoleName": "IT Support"
    }
```

If I log the details object passed to the selectItem method I can see the data is correct.  It just doesn't seem to be correct when assigned to the editable property.

Apologies if this isn't very clear. Here is a link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/TL6LW/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having is from the binding on your `select` in the editor. Knockout ensures that your current value is a valid selection or it sets it to the first entry. In your case your editable copy does not have the same reference to item in your `EmployeeRoles` array.  Even though they look the same they are not equal to each other, because they are not the same reference.

An easy fix might be to do something like:

```
self.SelectEmployee = function(e){
    self.Selected(e);
    var copy = ko.toJS(e);
    copy.Role = e.Role(); //get the actual reference
    self.Editable(new Employee(copy));
    self.isOpen(true);
};
```

So, we still use `ko.toJS` to make a clean copy, but then stick the actual reference to the `Role` on the copy.

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rVYrB/

Your sample is a good example of using this pattern with a pop-up dialog.